# javascript: fetch day of the week based on a specific date

Tags: javascript, date

I searched stackoverflow but did not find a solution to my problem.

I have a specific date say `2014-05-20` and I want to get the Day of the week for the mentioned date.

I tried the following

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getDay());
```

But this return the Current Day. What I require is the day based on the given date!

I also tried

```
var givendate = '2014-05-20';
new Date(givendate)
```

But the above does not generate anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question both code you combine and check answer is get on yourself without my answer still i show you code,

#### Check this <kbd>[**Demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3Ye8/1/)</kbd>

#### JavaScript

```
var givendate = '2014-05-20';
var date = new Date(givendate);
console.log(date.getDay());
```

#### Console log

```
2
```

Comment: a pretty use of `<kbd>`, isn't it??

Answer (score 1):

you may try

```
var date = new Date(2014, 05, 20).getDay(); // Date(year, month, date)
console.log(date);
```

you will get integer 0 for sunday - 6 for saturday