# days Of Week on page

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript newbie. I am learning and I am trying to get the day of week and write it to the document. I am using an array and switch case.

Check my code:

```
var currentDate=new Date();
var currentDay=currentDate.getDay();
var daysOfWeek=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];

switch(currentDay){
    case 0:
    document.write('Today is  <b>' +daysOfWeek[0]);

    break;
    case 1:

    break;
    case 2:

    break;
    case 3:

    break;
    case 4:

    break;
    case 5:

    break;

    case 6:

    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

It's working fine but I need to know whether this the best possible code i can write or if I can improve it.

Comment: What is `statements_1`?

Comment: What is the `switch` statement supposed to be good for? You can directly access the right array element via the day number, no need for a switch statement at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the day of week and the month of the year?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year)

Comment: What is your definition of "best"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One better way of doing this (while keeping your general approach) would be:

```
var currentDate=new Date();
var currentDay=currentDate.getDay();
var daysOfWeek=["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"]; 
document.write('Today is  <b>' +daysOfWeek[currentDay] + '</b>');
```

Comment: @S Mac Yes Thanks man i was thinking of this.. :)

Comment: `document.write`? I wish the DOM API was easier. I feel I need a shower when I see it. :/