# How can I retrieve the day of the week from date

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework

I need to retrieve the day of the week from the date.
For example: 10/01/2017 corresponds to Tuesday.
I'm using Robot Framework in which I can integrate javascript or python langage.
Any help please?

Comment: I think your question the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [which day of week given a date python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can use `weekday` in order to parse the date number.

```
from dateutil import parser
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
days_of_week = parser.parse('10/01/2017 ', dayfirst=True).weekday()
print(days[days_of_week])
```

**note** that `dayfirst` here is to say that first element in datetime that you put in is day instead of month

See more on [which day of week given a date python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/which-day-of-week-given-a-date-python) as mentioned in comment by TemporalWolf

Answer (score 2):

you can directly use Robot Framework [DateTime](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html) library here.

if you want the day as abbrivated (Mon, Tue, Wed ..etc) use the below format

```
*** Settings ***
Library   DateTime
*** TestCases ***
Date Convertion 
       [Arguments] ${Date}
       ${Day}=    Convert Date    ${Date}    result_format=%a
       [Return]   ${Day}
```

if want the day in full name format (Monday, Tuesday, ..etc) you should use the below format

```
${Day}=    Convert Date    ${Date}    result_format=%A
```

Both, I verified they are working fine, getting the proper result.

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can do extend date object:

```
Date.prototype.getWeekDay = function() {
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
return weekday[this.getDay()];
}
```

you can call date.getWeekDay();

See more on [How to get the day of week and the month of the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year)