# get current date and check if it is "Day X"

Tags: java, android-studio

I´m wring an App which checks if today is for example if its at the moment sunday.

I have `Date today = new Date();` and i want to know if it is a sunday

Comment: The information you need is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822852/how-to-get-the-day-of-week-and-the-month-of-the-year#4822882 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date .getDay() is @deprecated so I suggest that you use Calendar

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if(Calendar.SUNDAY == day) {
        ...
    }
```