# How to turn a period of date into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to turn a period of date in an array? For example, I have a period of date from 1 March 2020 to 29 April 2020, how can I turn it into an array shown below?

```
    period = [{day: "Sun", date: "1", month: "Mar", year: "2020"}, ..., 
{day: "Wed",date: "29", month: "Apr", year: "2020"}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show what code you have tried to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create array from date range follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/50398144/4964569

and get day in date follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822882/4964569

And use `map` function to generate your required

```
var getDaysArray = function(s,e) {for(var a=[],d=new Date(s);d<=e;d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)){ a.push(new Date(d));}return a;};

var dateRange = getDaysArray(new Date('2020-03-10'), new Date('2020-04-29'));
var days =  ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

var result = dateRange.map(function(elem){

     var obj =  {
       day: days[elem.getDay()],
       date: elem.getDate(),
       month: elem.getMonth(),
       year: elem.getFullYear()

     }

     return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

```js
var getDaysArray = function(s,e) {for(var a=[],d=new Date(s);d<=e;d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)){ a.push(new Date(d));}return a;};

var dateRange = getDaysArray(new Date('2020-03-10'), new Date('2020-04-29'));
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];

var result = dateRange.map(function(elem){
  
     var obj =  {
       day: days[elem.getDay()],
       date: elem.getDate(),
       month: elem.getMonth(),
       year: elem.getFullYear()
      
     }
     
     return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

In traditional way you can do it like this

```
    var startDate = new Date('2020-03-10');
    var endDateDate = new Date('2020-03-12');
    var arr = [];

    var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

    while(startDate.getTime() !== endDateDate.getTime()) {
       startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
       arr.push({
          day: days[startDate.getDay()], 
          date: startDate.getDate(), 
          month: startDate.getMonth(), 
          year: startDate.getYear()
       })
    }

    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var start = new Date('March 1, 2020');
var period = [];

for(var i=1; i<=60; i++){

  if( i == 32 )
    start = new Date('April 1, 2020');

  if( i <= 31 )
    start.setDate(i);  
  else
    start.setDate(i - 31);  

  var dateString = start.toDateString().split(' ');

  period.push({
    day: dateString[0], 
    date: dateString[2], 
    month: dateString[1], 
    year: dateString[3]
  });
  
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(period) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two Dates as your range delimiters. If not, you can create them this way:

```
var startDate = new Date('1 March 2020')
var endDate = new Date('29 April 2020')
```

Then, you have to increase the first date by one day until you reach the last date. To increase the first date by one day you can do this:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
```

You can get the day and the month from a Date with `date.getDay()` and `date.getMonth()`, but those methods will return numbers. To get the actual names you can do this:

```
var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

var startDateDay = days[startDate.getDay()]
var startDateMonth = months[startDate.getMonth()]
```

And then, you iterate:

```
var period = []

while (startDate <= lastDate) {
  period.push({
    day: days[startDate.getDay()],
    date: startDate.getDate(),
    month: months[startDate.getMonth()],
    year: startDate.getYear()
  })
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
}
```

And that's it. Here's a fiddle with a working example:

```js
var startDate = new Date('1 March 2020')
var endDate = new Date('29 April 2020')

var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

var period = []

while (startDate <= endDate) {
  period.push({
    day: days[startDate.getDay()],
    date: startDate.getDate(),
    month: months[startDate.getMonth()],
    year: startDate.getFullYear()
  })
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)
}

console.log(period)
```