# jquery DateTimePicker - Grab day of week in selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to add a hidden field when a user selects a date to show the day that it rests on. I looked in the documentation on using the dateFormat but can't seem to render this. So the date shows up in the field like: 01/01/2024, but I want the option to either add the day in the field value or have it as a hidden field and I can display it elsewhere. IE: 01/01/2024 Monday

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ The jQuery DateTimePicker

```
$("input.Date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $("#" + this.id + "_month").attr("value", new Date(dateText).getMonth() + 1);
        $("#" + this.id + "_day").attr("value", new Date(dateText).getDate());
        $("#" + this.id + "_year").attr("value", new Date(dateText).getFullYear());
        $("#" + this.id + "_changeTime").val(Date.now()).trigger('change');
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1900:2050',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    showOn: 'both',
    buttonText: 'Date',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    closeText: 'Close',
    showAnim: '',
    dayNamesShort: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4822852/2181514) and applying to the jquery-ui datepicker, you can get the weekday name two ways:  using an array or toLocaleTimeString()

Giving updated snippet, using both methods:

```js
$("input.date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("#" + this.id + "_changeTime").val(Date.now()).trigger('change');

    var currentDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");

    var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    var day = days[currentDate.getDay()];
    var month = months[currentDate.getMonth()];

    $("#" + this.id + "_day").attr("value", day);
    $("#" + this.id + "_month").attr("value", month);

    var options = {
      weekday: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
      hour12: false
    };
    $("#" + this.id + "_date").attr("value", currentDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-us', options));
  },
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1900:2050',
  showButtonPanel: true,
  showOn: 'both',
  buttonText: 'Date',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  closeText: 'Close',
  showAnim: '',
  dayNamesShort: true
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input class='date' id='dt'>
<input id='dt_month'>
<input id='dt_day'>
<input id='dt_date'>
<input id='dt_changeTime'>
```

Although it can be harder to configure initially, I'd suggest using `toLocaleTimeString` with options as you can then change the locale simply by changing the locale string and don't have to add your own translations.